# Is there a way to sort a list of strings by ending substring in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of strings where I need to sort it by the ending substring. For example, assume we have these strings in the list:

> **Get_USER_By_ID**
>
> **Get_Product_By_Name**
>
> **Get_Product_By_ID**
>
> **Get_Location_By_Name**
>
> **...**

I Need to sort it so that all the functions matching the same By_ are after each other

I could loop over the list, and create many new lists, and if the string contains a specific string (i.e. By_ID), I add it to its related List.

I want to sort them in the same list (same as if I say sort ascending or descending for instance) rather than creating many new lists (in my case I have to create 9 new lists)

Comment: Is the naming always consistent in some way? i.e. they always have "By_" in them?

Comment: yep it is consistent

Comment: You can do it using swapping.

Comment: `names.OrderBy(name => name.Split(new[] {"By_"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Last())`

Comment: let me test it, 1 min

Comment: throws this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. "

Comment: you just need to add `ToList()` to the call suggested by @Fabio

Answer (score 2):

You could create [Custom Comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8). IComparer defines how to compare objects of type T. This could be used with List.Sort for customized Sorting of the collection. For example, for the input collection

```
var strList = new List<string>
            {
             "Get_USER_By_ID",
             "Get_Product_By_Name",
             "Get_Product_By_ID",
             "Get_Location_By_Name"
             };
```

You could sort by

```
strList.Sort(new CustomStringComparer());
```

Or using Linq

```
 var result = strList.OrderBy(x=>x,new CustomStringComparer());
```

Where CustomStringComparer is defined as

```
public class CustomStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private Regex _regex = new Regex(@"By_(?<Tag>[\S]*)",RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public int Compare(string first, string second)
    {
        var firstSubString = _regex.Match(first).Groups["Tag"].Value;
        var secondSubString = _regex.Match(second).Groups["Tag"].Value;
        return firstSubString.CompareTo(secondSubString);
    }
}
```

Ouput

```
Get_USER_By_ID 
Get_Product_By_ID 
Get_Product_By_Name 
Get_Location_By_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(str => str.Split(new[] {"By_"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
               .Last()).ToList();
```